# What EURO exchanges have web APIs currently?

Tags: exchanges, trading, api

I'm wondering what exchanges in that operate in native euro, who most likely support sepa transactions have web apis?

Bitcoin-24.com was great until they had banking problems. now who is left? Is BTCe the only one?

Comment: I just tried again to find a comprehensive Bitcoin exchange overview, but the best thing I found is this: [https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins)

Comment: Kraken and Bitfinex and I'm sure others, not sure if you can deposit to Bitfinex tho.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few exchanges in Europe with APIs. Use the Bitdango exchange search to find exchanges in European countries:

http://bitdango.com/exchanges?countries=BG,CZ,DE,FI,FR,GB,HR,MT,NL,NO,PL,SE,SI

Or use the Bitdango market search to find markets that use Euros as quote currency:

http://bitdango.com/markets?quoteCurrencies=EUR

Answer (score 0):

The highest volume of BTCEUR is on kraken for a long time already.

---

docs for API method: https://www.kraken.com/help/api#get-ticker-info
API call: https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR